# Voting down is negative karma. Use it wisely

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delaying comments/up votes/down votes after a question/answer is posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76213/delaying-comments-up-votes-down-votes-after-a-question-answer-is-posted)

Down-votes are a way of feedback, but should not be the primary way of feedback.

Would it be good to disallow down-voting for a short period of time, while OP is reviewing the comments and correcting his malformed question?

Say 5 or 10 minutes after the original post was made.

Comment: Votes (up/down) are the primary way of feedback. Deal with it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why shouldn't the OP take care of not wasting the reader's time to start with?

Comment: I have to offset all my good karma somehow...

Comment: In case you didn't know: [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: [Downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) and, commenting is *not* required for downvotes.  If you get one, consider yourself lucky, as voting is *intended* to be anonymous.

Comment: When a question has been edited, it is possible to change your vote (for example from down- to up-vote). Maybe after an edit users could get notifications like: "Question ... was edited after you down-voted it. Care to have a look at it again?" ?

Comment: Problem:  Downvoted questions.  Solution:  Don't ask crappy questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea: it encourages users to post malformed questions. Consider that while OPs are reforming their question and responding to comments, many repliers are busy writing responses, which then have to be altered to account for the amended question.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this would be a good idea.

Voting is used to set apart the good questions from the bad ones.

The immense number of questions posted every minute to Stack Overflow would make it almost impossible to actually downvote bad questions, defeating to purpose of voting in the process.

This would also discourage putting enough effort in the question in the first place. A malformed question that gets radically edited is a waste of everybody's time.

Furthermore, if the OP corrects his question, all votes can reverse their vote (if they choose so).